# "Error getting session" in websphere but working fine in jboss

Tags: web-services, webserver, websphere, restful-authentication, http-authentication

I am calling a RestfulWebservice present in Websphere server from a javascript or browser by adding Authorization in the request header but getting "Error getting session". After digging into the code I found that Authorization header values are getting extracted from the header and it is showing error while connecting to a URL. This URL contains a call to another Rest webservice in the same server and is confirmed to be correct. The app is working only when it is already logged in that server from another tab and calling the webservice.

Now, this app is working as expected when a Jboss server is used.

My question is - Is there any settings in the websphere server which can resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey! better you try to add the exception details/stack trace that you are currently getting when the app is deployed in Websphere. It is very hard to answer a question without knowing the exact problem. You have to be more specific to get the proper answer.

Comment: You need to verify in which component you have the error. This looks like custom error message, so it either can be from first service or from the other one. Add stack trace and failing code.

Comment: You have some potential problems in `com.dstawd.rest.authentication.BasicAuthenticationFilter`. Add it also to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I have an AuthenticationFilter to call first and I was passing wrong parameter in the request header. After passing correct parameter in the request header which is verified by AuthenticationFilter, I am getting expected result. Thanks.